# What's the recommend way of cloning a jOOQ Record object?

Tags: java, jooq

It seems like you can't create a copy constructor, you can't make it implement cloneable.

I was thinking of using reflection to iterate over every attribute on the child class but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like you can't create a copy constructor, you can't make it implement cloneable.

You can implement these things in the code generator easily yourself. In both cases, [you will need to generate some custom code](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code/), and in the case of `Cloneable`, you will need to write a generator strategy ([programmatic](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/) or [configurative](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/)), which adds the `Cloneable` interface to all generated records.

If you're not using generated records, or if you want to clone any arbitrary record, you can still use one of the many [`Record.into()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#into-java.lang.Class-) [methods](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#into-org.jooq.Table-), which copy record contents into a new type.

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful. Do you know if we could also add an expression to the generator? I'd only want to add `implements Cloneable` to a few records and not to every single one of them.

Comment: @LukeXu: Please read the linked docs related to the generator strategy, in particular the [configurative](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/) one. Look for `<recordImplements>`

Answer (score 2):

To copy a record I have used the `UpdatableRecord.copy()` method.

```
/**
 * Duplicate this record (in memory) and reset all fields from the primary
 * key or main unique key, such that a subsequent call to {@link #store()}
 * will result in an <code>INSERT</code> statement.
 *
 * @return A new record, distinct from <code>this</code> record.
 */
R copy();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jooq 3.16.5, a simple way to create a copy it to use the `into(Field<?>... fields)` method on the original instance, essentially copying all the fields into a new record:

```
import org.jooq.Record;

Record original = ...
Record copied = original.into(original.fields);
```